# О корнях слов «потреблять» и «наследник»

Tags: морфемика

Какой корень в слове **потребить**? В интернете пишут разную информацию. Не смогла найти точных данных. Связано ли это слово с глаголом "требовать"?

Еще интересует слово **наследник**. Читала здесь об этом: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1724571-odnokorennye-slova-k-slovu-sled.html
У всех разные мнения. Какого придерживаться?

Answer (score 1):

Вы задали очень интересный вопрос. Думаю, однозначно ответить на него не получится.

Морфемный словарь Тихонова в этих словах приставок (уже) не выделяет. Если же обратиться к этимологическим словарям (Фасмера, Крылова и т. д.), то увидим, что слова *наследник* и *след* (*следить*, а еще лучше *следовать* — ведь наследник и есть в некотором смысле "следующий" в роду) действительно общего происхождения, как и *потребный* (необходимый, ср. *требуемый* — а отсюда в конечном счете и *потреблять*) и *требовать*. Но надо заметить, что оба слова были заимствованы еще из старославянского, т. е. не позднее 13–14 веков, а то и раньше (причем уже вместе с соответствующими префиксами).

Поэтому, думаю, итоговый ответ будет таким: хотя эти пары слов действительно *исторически* однокоренные (происходят от общих корней), в *современном* русском языке приставки уже не выделяются, а включаются в состав корней. (Это далеко не уникальные случаи, так, например, подобное произошло со словами *привет*, *пример* и т. д.)